# Getting code behind a programm

Tags: c, readfile

I want to make a program that analyzes the commands of an `.exe` file and take some decisions regarding the content. The problem is here: I copied a `.exe` from a C project in my program folder (which also uses C). I changed its extension from `.exe` to `.txt` and made this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int apare(char a, char s[]) //this function search a character in a string.
{
    printf("merge");
    int nr=strlen(s),i;
    for(i=0; i<nr; i++)
    {
        if(a==s[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * f=fopen("program in C.txt","r");
    char c,s[10000]="abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ _-+=.,<>?!@#$%^&*()1234567890{}[];:'";//The characters I want to be printed
    int a=1,k=0;//k is only used to printf "\n" when 1100 characters have been displayed on a line
    while(a)
    {
        c=fgetc(f);//A char is read
        if(c!=EOF)//If no error occurs than display the character if it is present in the string.
        {
            if(apare(c,s))
            {
                printf("%c",c);
                k++;
            }
        }
        else if(ferror) //If an error occurs than read the next char
            c=fgetc(f);
        else  //If EOF than stop reading
            a=0;
        if(k==100)
        {
            k=0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that this program shows the "strange" characters too. The role of this program is to get only readable parts. Why does this happen?

Comment: @iharob :) see `int apare(char a, char s[])...`

Comment: You could format you code such that HUMANS can read it too.

Comment: maybe you can consider using `isprint()` to check for the printable character...

Comment: Also, what is `read(f)` it's not what it seems to be, is `read()` a function defined by you but not posted here?

Comment: Why would you rename the file to `.txt`?

Comment: And, are you trying to decompile the *.exe* files?

Comment: I am trying to make a program that finds out what an ,exe does and I'm not sure how to read this .exe I don't even now if it's possible. I asked earlier if it is but the question disappeared.

Comment: @Alex "I am trying to make a program that finds out what an ,exe does" sounds like what you really want is know under the term: decompiling. This is not trivial and often not even completely possible and is not achieved by the way you think. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler for further information

Comment: @Alex there is a fundamental difference between a program and the corresponding C code. The latter is _not_ a program by itself thus you can't retrieve the exact C code from the executable.

Answer (score 1):

> I changed its extension from .exe to .txt

That doesn't make it *actual text*.  Compiled executables are binary files.  It's *possible* that they coincidentally contain *some* readable characters within the ASCII range of the English alphabet here and there, depending on the encoding you use to read them.  But that's just a coincidence.

You can't decompile an application into its original code just by renaming the file.

Comment: Well I asked how to decompile  but my question got deleted and i tried on my own...

Comment: @Alex: "decompile" is exactly the word you should be looking up on Google as you research this.  Attempting to write your own decompiler from scratch is... ambitious.

Comment: @Alex: decompilation is ambition.  You may want to search for disassembly instead.  While writing a disassembler is still a daunting task, it is no where as difficult as writing a tool to do decompilation.   If you still want to attempt decompilation, Cifuentes dissertation (http://zyloid.com/recomposer/files/decompilation_thesis.pdf) is a good starting point.

Comment: @thurizas: Thank you, mate! That was what I was looking for. A disassembler! All I need is to obtain the code (in assembly if possible).

Comment: @Alex: glad to help.  Instead of writing one from scratch, you may want to look at some of the frameworks out there.  Capstone (http://www.capstone-engine.org/) or BARF (https://github.com/programa-stic/barf-project). There are others around, but I have personal experience with each of these frameworks.  Also, there are commercial disassemblers out there, IDA-Pro is the industry standard.  You may have better luck with questions on the reverse engineering SO site (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).  Cheers, T.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Linux/Unix system, there is a good chance there is a manual page which explains the layout of an executable file.  For example:

```
man elf
```

Your system may also have a couple of tools to do a basic analysis of an executable file, which you may find instructive:

```
man objdump
man readelf
```

There is also likely a C include file, perhaps `#include <elf.h>` which may help write your program.  But be aware, you have started a daunting task.  And if the executable file has been stripped of its symbols, even more so.

Here's an example of using objdump to disassemble:

```
# objdump -d moai.2014.10.07
moai.2014.10.07:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000400e48 <_init>:
  400e48:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400e4c:       e8 4b 03 00 00          callq  40119c <call_gmon_start>
  400e51:       e8 da 03 00 00          callq  401230 <frame_dummy>
  400e56:       e8 55 51 00 00          callq  405fb0 <__do_global_ctors_aux>
  400e5b:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400e5f:       c3                      retq  
     ...
```